# Bulleted lists in tcolorbox within a Markdown document

Tags: tcolorbox, pandoc, markdown, bullets

Am using the following code in my Markdown preamble to use tcolorboxes within my markdown code:

````
header-includes:
- |
  ```{=latex}
  \usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \newtcolorbox{norm-box}{colback=gray!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=gray!60!black}
  \newtcolorbox{info-box}{colback=cyan!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=cyan!60!black}
  \newtcolorbox{warn-box}{colback=orange!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=orange!80!black}
  \newtcolorbox{error-box}{colback=red!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=red!75!black}
  \newtcolorbox{attn-box}{colback=green!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=green!75!black}
````

```
pandoc-latex-environment:
  tcolorbox: [box]
  norm-box: [norm]
  info-box: [info]
  warn-box: [warn]
  error-box: [error]
  attn-box: [attn]
...
```

Then, in my Markdown text, I am using this code to generate a lightbox with a header and some bulleted lists:

```
::: info
**Objectives:**
- test
- test
- test
- test
:::
```

When I go to run Pandoc and generate a PDF from the Markdown file, I get the following error message:

```
Error running filter pandoc-latex-environment:
Error in $.blocks[1].c[1][14].c: cannot unpack array of length 3 into a tuple of length 2
```

If I take away the last bulleted item, it compiles no problem.

```
::: info
**Objectives:**
- test
- test
- test
test
:::
```

This seems like a bug to me. Any other ways I can create a bulleted list inside of tcolorbox?

Note: It does work just fine if I move everything for my tcolorbox in my Markdown to LaTeX.

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=cyan!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=cyan!60!black,title=\textbf{Objectives}]
\begin{itemize}
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

But as these docs are used by plenty of non-educated LaTeX users, it needs to stay as simple as possible.
Thanks.

Comment: I guess many users here including myself, are not as familiar with pandoc as you, so could you provide a step-by-step guide for how to reproduce your problem?

Comment: This is  a known bug: https://github.com/chdemko/pandoc-latex-environment/issues/9

Comment: You could use and adapt the [latex-div.lua](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/8824c26690145c133ce8aeeec6fe59d23baaa1ce/inst/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua) filter which ships with RMarkdown.